# what is correct way to define Many2Many, Many2One in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask-mongoengine

I am creating a data model for my new project where I have to use Many2Many, Many2One, One2Many reference using flask-mongoengine. Can someone describe how to define Many2Many and other reference field using mongoengine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the most common ways to do it:

1) 1-to-many with a simple ReferenceField

```
class Client(Document):
    name = StringField()

    @property
    def account(self):
          return Account.objects(client=self).get()  

class Account(Document):
    client = ReferenceField(Client)

bob = Client(name='Bob').save()
acc1 = Account(client=bob).save()
acc2 = Account(client=bob).save()
```

2) Many-2-Many with a list(ReferenceField)

```
class Client(Document):
    name = StringField()

    @property
    def accounts(self):
          return Account.objects(client=self)  

class M2MAccount(Document):
    clients = ListField(ReferenceField(Client))

bob = Client(name='Bob').save()
john = Client(name='John').save()
m2m_acc = M2MAccount(clients=[bob, john]).save()
```

Note that the @property is optional, its just for convenience

Comment: I did exactly what you have mentioned, but again encountered with the following error " 
    department = db.ListField(ReferenceField('Department'))
NameError: name 'ReferenceField' is not defined
"

Comment: the problem has been solved "db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Department'))"